# All my efforts to install VLC on RHEL 7 are futile

Tags: vlc-media-player, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have tried to install VLC on my RHEL Server 7 in many ways. At the end the final result is failure. I am a newbie to Linux but this is really a problem.
Can anyone tell me what to do?

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: You should specify EXACTLY the "many solutions" you tried and EXACTLY how they each failed. Like: I typed "blah" in a terminal and pressed enter. I got error message "foo".

Comment: Can you please list what you have tried and how it has failed?

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086/23408).